# MSI Bigfoot gaming LAN Killer e2200 not working

Tags: 13.04, ethernet

I have done **lspci -vnn** and got this

```
    02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e091] (rev 13)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device [1462:10be]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at f7300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
```

Then I went [here!](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332)
I Figured that the [1969:e091] (rev 13) is the same hardware.
I typed in **sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers**. This gives and error because it needs a version.

I would like to know how to tell what version I will need? I'm using *Ubuntu 13.04*.

Answer (score 0):

This hardware is not yet supported by default.
Look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008332 
there is a patched version of the alx driver working with this ethernet